# How to get a random sample given 2 arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi there I am working with a Sci Kit learn data set, digits and I Split the data
So I have X_train and Y_train arrays

The arrays are related in such a way that the index x[0] belongs to y[0]

```
print x_train.shape 
(1347, 64)
print y_train.shape
(1347)
print set(y_train) 
(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

I would like to extract a random sample from x_train given the set(y), i.e. To resample my data by extracting just one random observation of the set(y).However I don´t know if I can do this with numpy or pandas, any one have an idea of how to deal with this????

Thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with a random sample from `x` given `set(y)`?

Comment: I edited my post, I am not sure if I am being clear with my question, thank you so much.

Comment: see my answer and let me know if this is what you need. Again it is not clear what you want to do. leave a comment under my answer if this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do.
The `set(y)` contains all the available labels of your dataset `X`.

In general (until you specify what you need), use `random.choice`:

You have this:

```
print set(y) 
(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Convert it first to a list:

```
index_all = list(set(y))
```

**Now, randomly sample the `set(y)`:**

```
# this is a random index (class/label) from 0 to 9.
random_index = np.random.choice(index_all, 1)
```

---

**Now, I see 2 possibilities (I believe you want the Case 2):**

**1)** Directly resample `x` based on this random index (random based on the `set(y)`)
Finally, if x is a numpy array:

```
x[random_index, :]
```

This returns a random observation of x based on the `set(y)`

**2)** Resample the `x` but get a random observation that has a label `y`. Label 'y' is defined randomly above (`random_index`)

```
x[y==random_index]
```

This returns a random observation of x that is associated with a label `y`.

Answer (score -1):

This is the approach I generally use for constructing a dataframe and extracting data from it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Dummy arrays for x and y
x_train = np.zeros((1347,64))
y_train = np.ones((1347))

#First we pair up the arrays according to their index using zip. Only use this 
#method if both arrays are of equal length.
training_dataset = list(zip(x_train,y_train))

#Next we load the dataset as a dataframe using Pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(data=training_dataset)
#Check that the dataframe is what you want
df.head()

#If you would like to extract a random row, you may use 
df.sample(n=1)

#Alternatively if you would like to extract a specific row (eg. 10th row aka index 9)
df.iloc[10]
```

I hope I've understood what you wanted to achieve but if not, feel free to let me know so I can amend my answer!

Sources:

[Pandas Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

[Selecting Rows and Columns in Pandas Dataframes](https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/#iloc-selection)